# add the rowindex to an element id html

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I'vve been trying to add teh row index to an element id but no luck.
I have a table with a loop inside of it, and i want to get the value of a specific elemnent inside of the table. But this only gives me the first row. 
My code is something like this:

```
<table>
<thead> <th></th></thead>
<tbody>
   <c:foreach items="${projectlist}" var="project">
     <tr> <td> <input type="text" id="name_**rowindex**" /></td></tr>
</c:foreach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i don't want to use varStatus because i will add another loop inside of teh table.

Thank u in advance

Comment: Any specific reason why you dont want to use varStatus ....just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `varStatus` you will have to maintain your own index.

```
<c:set var="myIndex" value="0" />

<c:foreach items="${projectlist}" var="project">
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="name_${myIndex}" /></td></tr>

    <c:set var="myIndex" value="${myIndex + 1}" />
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: eventually , i used var status. Thank yo for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple solution .Though not sure why you dont want to use **varStatus**

```
<c:foreach items="${projectlist}" var="project"
varStatus="pStatus">
     <tr> <td> <input type="text" id="name_${pStatus}" /></td></tr>
</c:foreach>
```